# visualize a list of colors/palette in R

Tags: r, color-palette

I have following data.frame with rgb values. Hence each row indicates a color.

```
pdf <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
r     g     b
0.374 0.183 0.528
0.374 0.905 0.337
0.051 0.662 0.028
0.096 0.706 0.898
0.876 0.461 0.628
0.415 0.845 0.286
0.596 0.07  0.523
0.724 0.101 0.673
0.847 0.434 0.937
0.588 0.885 0.604
0.481 0.366 0.337
0.142 0.075 0.276
0.819 0.737 0.658
0.91  0.722 0.979
0.969 0.012 0.451
0.887 0.536 0.123
0.432 0.967 0.446
0.927 0.125 0.332
0.381 0.646 0.656
0.04  0.898 0.798
")
```

How can I visualize these colors? This can be either as bars of color or a palette or a pie chart. I tried to use following method but could not fit it in my data:

```
pie(rep(1,20), col=rainbow(20))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`image()` will work well here if you convert the colors via `rgb()`

```
image(1:nrow(ddf), 1, as.matrix(1:nrow(ddf)), 
      col=rgb(ddf$r, ddf$g, ddf$b),
      xlab="", ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 62):

I think the simplest option is scales. This also has the advantage of showing the hex values in the colours.

```
library(scales)
pal <- rgb(ddf$r, ddf$g, ddf$b)
show_col(pal)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the solution using `image` you could also use `polygon` and create a quite similar plot:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0, nrow(ddf)), ylim=c(0,1))

for (i in 1:nrow(ddf)) {

  row <- ddf[i,]
  color <- rgb(red=row$r, green=row$g, blue=row$b)
  polygon(x=c(i-1, i, i, i-1), y=c(0, 0, 1, 1), col = color)
}
```

Comment: Good alternative method. Polygon() is a useful function.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=1:nrow(ddf), y = 1, fill=factor(1:nrow(ddf)), geom="tile") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rgb(ddf$r, ddf$g, ddf$b)) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the hues package:

```
library("hues")

pal <- c("#351d34", "#f5ccb5", "#159ea2", "#d05d6c", "#ec4934")

swatch(pal)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems a new package. I had asked this question 9 years back!

Comment: hahaha I haven't noticed it. But it works pretty good in 2023 :)

Answer (score 2):

Convert to R color with rgb(), plot with ggplot using geom_tile (extending the answer from @Matifou), and add text label.

With the original post data:

```
    # a palette is a named vector
    myPalette=rgb(pdf)
    names(myPalette) = paste("row", 1:nrow(pdf))
    
    # create data that references the palette
    colorKey = data.frame(colorName=names(myPalette))
    # plot with ggplot, referencing the palette
    ggplot(data=colorKey, aes(x=1, y = 1:nrow(colorKey), fill=colorName, label=colorName)) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_manual(values = myPalette) +
      theme_void()+
      theme(legend.position="none") + 
      geom_text()
```

[image: horizontal bar for each color]

SECOND EXAMPLE - for text labels

```
    myPalette =  c(
      buttercup = "#6AD749",
      bubbles = "#18B4E5",
      blossum = "#DF76A0")
    
    colorKey = data.frame(colorName=names(myPalette))
    ggplot(data=colorKey, aes(x=1, y = 1:nrow(colorKey), fill=colorName, label=colorName)) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_manual(values = myPalette) +
      theme_void()+
      theme(legend.position="none") + 
      geom_text()
```

[image: image of 3 color bars with labels]